# imagecopyresampled converts image to black

Tags: php

I am trying to resize an image after uploading but the image is always converted to black. Though the image has the right dimension, it just shows black. I'm not sure where I messed up. I already searched SO to no avail.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $full_path)){

        $orig_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($full_path);
        $image_info = getimagesize($full_path); 
        $width_orig  = $image_info[0]; // current width as found in image file
        $height_orig = $image_info[1]; // current height as found in image file

        if($width_orig > $height_orig){
            $width = 105;
            $ratio = $width/$width_orig;
            $height = $height_orig*$ratio;
        }else{
            $height = 360;
            $ratio = $height/$height_orig;
            $width = $width_orig*$ratio;
        }

        $destination_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        imagecopyresampled($destination_image, $orig_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
        imagejpeg($destination_image, $full_path, 100);

}
```

Comment: Does `imagecopyresampled` return TRUE or FALSE? If it comes back FALSE, that means there was a failure of some sort.

Comment: @BenVisness It returns false. I have no idea where the failure is.

Comment: What does `imagecreatefromjpeg` return? I would start by verifying that all four variables at the top have the values you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Check image type before function imagecreatefromjpeg() to be shure.
Something like this:

```
$image_type = exif_imagetype($full_path);
switch ($image_type)
    {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF : $orig_image = imagecreatefromgif($file); break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG : $orig_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);  break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG : $orig_image = imagecreatefrompng($file); break;
        //...
        default: echo 'Wrong image type';  break;
    }
```

Comment: Already did but it still persists. If it helps, imagecopyresampled returns false. I'm not sure why.